# How create two tables in relationship using SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to create two tables `Category` and `Product` in SQLite.
Category table should be parent and Product table should be a child.
I created two tables in this way, and I do not know it is a good approach:

```
CREATE TABLE Category (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR,
    category_description VARCHAR,
    image_path VARCHAR
):

CREATE TABLE Product (
    product_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name VARCHAR,
    product_description VARCHAR,
    product_numberOfProduct integer,
    product_image_path VARCHAR,
    product_price integer,
    category_id integer NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES Category(id)
);
```

I want to create a query for searching all products from `category_name` and something like that.

Comment: You'l want to change that `BIGINT PRIMARY KEY` to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`  in the Category table for best results, btw: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: And `VARCHAR` to `TEXT` while you're at it: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is *almost* spot on.  The major deficiency in your solution is that if a given product can belong to more than one category, then your schema would be duplicating all of that product's metadata for each product-category relationship.  The standard way to deal with this is to create a third junction table, which mainly exists to store the relationships between products and their categories.  So, your junction table might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Category (
    product_id integer,
    category_id integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id, category_id)
)
```

From your current `Product` table you would remove the reference to the `category_id`.

As an example query, if you wanted to find out all category names of a given product, you could try:

```
SELECT
    c.category_name
FROM Category c
INNER JOIN Product_Category pc
    ON c.id = pc.category_id
INNER JOIN Product p
    ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE
    p.product_name = 'some product name';
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks one more time.