# How create query for finding product for category

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables `Category` and `Product_Category`. This is my `Category` table :

```
CREATE TABLE Category (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR,
    category_description TEXT,
    image_path VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE Product_Category (
    product_id integer,
    category_id integer,
    description TEXT,
    numberOfProduct integer,
    image TEXT,
    price integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id, category_id)
)
```

I am want to create one query to find all `Product_Category` for my `category_name` in `Category` table. Also, I want to query for find specific `Product_Category`    and specific `Category`.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text ´, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: It would be nice if you could show some of the data you currently have in the database or test data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How create two tables in relationship using SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54766863/how-create-two-tables-in-relationship-using-sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi look first I recommend you use the same data types for the related columns.

In the Category table you used the id as **BIGINT**, use the same in the **category_id** column of the **Product_Category** table

```
CREATE TABLE Category (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, // -----> BIGINT
    category_name VARCHAR,
    category_description TEXT,
    image_path VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE Product_Category (
    product_id integer,
    category_id integer, // -------> here should also be BIGINT
    description TEXT,
    numberOfProduct integer,
    image TEXT,
    price integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id, category_id)
)


SELECT
  PC.*
FROM category AS C
INNER JOIN Product_Category AS PC
  ON PC.category_id = C.id
WHERE C.category_name = "value" ----> **Here goes the value of the category you want to search**
```

**NOTE:** C.category_name = "value" the value must be exactly the same in order to obtain results.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables as:

```
SELECT c.category_name, p.product_id, p.category_id, p.description, p.numberOfProduct, p.image, p.price FROM category c 
LEFT JOIN Product_Category p ON c.id=p.category_id
```

Comment: I have this syntax error: `-- At line 1:
SELECT c.category_name, p.product_id, p.category_id, p.description, p.numberOfProduct, p.image, p.price FROM #category
-- Result: near "#category": syntax error`

Comment: @SInsansun it works now. I forgot to omit the # while posting it.

Answer (score 0):

to find all Product_Category for  category_name you can use join:

```
select pc.* from category as cn inner join Product_Category as pc on 
pc.category_id = cn.id where cn.category_name = "name_of_category"
```

Comment: I do not have an error when I run but the result is 0. But my category is not empty, have one colone.

Comment: specify the category name